# C# Docusign API Launcher error ArgumentException: The 'ClientId' option must be provided. (Parameter 'ClientId')

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am receiving this error after filling in the config details (such as integration key and client secret) into the `appsettings.example.json` file. I downloaded Code-Examples-CSharp from the Docusign Github and was able to run the ISSExpresss in VS2019 and it takes me to http://localhost:8080/ and then I am receiving this error below.  I don't think I am missing any other config areas, but I'm new to Docusign APIs so please let me know if I am.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> ArgumentException: The 'ClientId' option must be provided. (Parameter 'ClientId')
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthOptions.Validate()
>
> ArgumentException: The 'ClientId' option must be provided. (Parameter 'ClientId')
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthOptions.Validate()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationOptions.Validate(string scheme)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass4_0<TOptions, THandler>.b__1(TOptions o)
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ValidateOptions.Validate(string name, TOptions options)
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory.Create(string name)
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor+<>c__DisplayClass11_0.b__0()
> System.Lazy.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
> System.Lazy.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, bool useDefaultConstructor)
> System.Lazy.CreateValue()
> System.Lazy.get_Value()
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache.GetOrAdd(string name, Func createOptions)
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor.Get(string name)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, string authenticationScheme)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy appsettings.example.json into appsettings.json and then update all the fields in it before you run this. You have to obtain an integration key from the DocuSign developer account which you can create for free.

Comment: Thanks Inbar that was the step I was missing, I did not notice that earlier. Thanks for guiding a newbie like me there! For future users with this error, "Create the appsettings.json (the configuration file) by using the example provided in appsettings.example.json."

Comment: that's a great idea, we would try to do that.